# What's the logic behind adjectives constructed with a hyphen?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, hyphenation, compounds

I'll give you a lovecraftian stanza:

> Thro’ the ghoul-guarded gateways of slumber,
>   Past the wan-moon’d abysses of night,
>   I have liv’d o’er my lives without number,
>   I have sounded all things with my sight;
>   And I struggle and shriek ere the daybreak, being driven to madness with fright.
>
> *Nemesis* — Howard Phillips Lovecraft

*Ghoul* is a noun, and *guarded* is the past participle of *to guard*. He combined both words to create an adjective to describe his "gateways of slumber" properly.

But then you have *wan-mooned*. An adjective plus the past participle of *to moon* or some bizarre usage of the noun *moon* to explicitly say that the "abysses of night are full with moons."

That's where I think: What's the logic behind this after all? To which extent I have the power of freedom to create my own bizarre adjectives by combining random words?

I could replace the second verse with:

> Past the wild-river’d clouds of mars

It would not make any sense, but the *logic* of *wild-river'd* is pretty much the same of *wan-moon'd*.

What's the *insanity-guarded* logic/rule behind this?

Comment: The abysses of night are not full of wan moons ... they are lit by a wan moon. Is a low-roofed house a house full of low roofs?

Comment: Bloody good example!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Wan-moon'd* is a perfectly ordinary English construction, in which *ADJ-NOUNed* is a compound adjective mean “exhibiting or marked by or provided with (an) ADJ NOUN”.  For instance:

> red-faced with exertion
>   brown-shirted minions
>   a one-legged man
>   horny-handed sons of toil
>   pluck bright honour from the pale-faced moon

Lovecraft's abysses of night are overlooked or (as Peter Shor suggests) lit (however inadequately) by a wan moon.

Answer (score 0):

Hyphens come in handy especially in examples like yours, where an adjective is used to describe another adjective, thereby acting as an adverb. The hyphen lets us know that the descriptor is acting like an adverb modifying the adjective, not as an adjective modifying the noun.

Is it an abyss that it both wan and moon'd? Or is it an abyss that is wan-moon'd? The hyphen answers that question. There are many more practical instances than in Lovecraftian verse, too.